# mySQL - Check Table for duplicates efficiently

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, duplicates

I have a table "people" where (for simplicity) everyone has an ID, this ID is not unique so two entries can have the same ID.
I now want to find all duplicates which I would do like this:

```sql
SELECT p1.Name, p2.Name
FROM Person p1 JOIN Person p2 ON p1.ID = p2.ID
```

Sample data would be something like this:

```
NAME ID

A    1
B    2
C    1
D    3
E    2
F    1
D    3
```

Result should be:

```
A,C
A,F
B,E
C,F
D,D
```

**But I would like to only compare entry A to all others, then B to all others EXCEPT A, etc.
How do I do this?**

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would also help.

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING etc.

Comment: If you add another (D, 3) row, should (D, D) be returned or not?

Comment: What's the expected result if you also add (F, 1)?

Comment: @jarlh It should be returned. (But isn't possible in our database, name is only used in this example not on the real database.)

Comment: With "F,1" it would return A,C - A,F - C,F. I'm sorry for my bad sample data. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you want:

```
SELECT p1.Name, p2.Name
FROM Person p1 
JOIN Person p2 ON p1.ID = p2.ID AND p1.Name < p2.Name
```

Comment: I applaud this solution.. just add a `ORDER BY p1.Name` to the end and I believe this is exactly what @Johannes-Nodop has asked for

Comment: @Simon, applaud if you're so inclined, but upvote if you want to show your appreciation. (Click on the grey upward pointing arrow over the number to the left of the answer.)

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, such a simple thing.
Thank you sir(or madame)! :)